# Parsing JSON string into columns using R - JSON string with inconsistent ordering of properties

Tags: r, jsonparser

I have a CSV with a JSON string with inconsistent ordering of the fields. So it looks like this:

```
Row 1: '{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}'
Row 2: '{"name":"Chuck", "car":black, "age":25}'
Row 3: '{"car":blue, "age":54, "name":"David"}'
```

I’m hoping to use R to parse this out into columns with the appropriate data. So I’d like to create a ‘name’ column, ‘age’ column, and ‘car’ column and have them populate with the appropriate data. Is there anyway to do this using JSONlite, or would I need to figure out a way to essentially query the JSON string for the property name (car, name, age) and populate that column with the subsequent value?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, the `RcppSimdJson` package can be used. Depending on the format of the data file we can

- either convert the data row by row using `fparse()`
- or read and convert the file in one go using `fload()`

#### Converting the data row by row

If the data file `json_data_1.csv` has the format

> ```
> {"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}
> {"name":"Chuck", "car":"black", "age":25}
> {"car":"blue", "age":54, "name":"David"}
> ```

(note that `blue` and `black` have been enclosed in double quotes to obey JSON syntax rules)

the JSON data need to be converted row by row, e.g.

```
library(magrittr)   # piping used to improve readability
readLines("json_data_1.csv") %>% 
  lapply(RcppSimdJson::fparse) %>% 
  data.table::rbindlist(fill = TRUE)
```

> ```
>     name age   car
> 1:  John  30  <NA>
> 2: Chuck  25 black
> 3: David  54  blue
> ```

#### Reading and converting the file in one go

If the data file `json_data_2.csv` has the format

> ```
> [
> {"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null},
> {"name":"Chuck", "car":"black", "age":25},
> {"car":"blue", "age":54, "name":"David"}
> ]
> ```

(note the square brackets and the commas which indicate an array in JSON syntax)

the file can be read and converted by one line of code:

```
RcppSimdJson::fload("json_data_2.csv")
```

> ```
>    name age   car
> 1  John  30  <NA>
> 2 Chuck  25 black
> 3 David  54  blue
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `jsonlite` library, but however in order to parse the data you must make some "adjustments" to your string. Lets say that you have the `df` as follows

```
my_df <- data.frame(column_1 = 
  c('{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}',
  '{"name":"Chuck", "car":"black", "age":25}',
  '{"car":"blue", "age":54, "name":
  "David"}')
)
```

You must have a valid `json` format in order to parse the data properly. In this case is an `array` json format, so the data must have `[` and `]`. Also each element must be separated by `,`. Be careful with the `strings`, each one must have `"<string>"`. (You didn't add it in your example with `blue` and `black` data)

With that in mind we can now make some code:

```
# Base R

# Add "commas" to sep each element
new_json_str <- paste(my_df$column_1, collapse = ",")

# Add "brackets" to the string
new_json_str <- paste("[", new_json_str, "]")

# Parse the JSON string with jsonlite
jsonlite::fromJSON(new_json_str)


# With dplyr library

my_df %>% 
    pull(column_1) %>%              # Get column as "vector"
    paste(collapse = ",") %>%       # Add "commas"
    paste("[", . ,"]") %>%          # Add "bracket" (`.` represents the current value, in this case vectors sep by ",")
    jsonlite::fromJSON()            # Parse json to df

# Result

#    name age   car
# 1  John  30  <NA>
# 2 Chuck  25 black
# 3 David  54  blue
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The dplyr approach worked really well, I have a lot to learn here but I appreciate the help. Quick Q - how does JSONlite know to organize components in the JSON string appropriately? For example, the ordering in the JSON strings is not consistent, but JSONlite seemed to put everything into the correct columns. Is that baked into the library?

Comment: You are welcome. I don't know the internal functionality of `jsonlite`, however I have an idea. `json` works with `key`: `value` data pairs. So in this sense `jsonlite` "take" the `key` as a column name and `value` as the "current" value of the row. If `value` doesn't exists it will fill it with `NA`.